# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService

Tags: node.js, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging for push notifications in a Flutter app using node.js + Typescript.

The FCM configurations for onLaunch and onResume were working fine, until I added Firebase dynamic links. Now, every time I receive a notification, the app crashes.

I have included click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK' in the notification payload as well.

I do not have an Application.java file, I am using Flutter Android Embedding V2 (Flutter Version >= 1.12) and hence, [no additional integration steps are required for Android](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview/#3-android-integration).

Error:

> D/AndroidRuntime(14785): Shutting down VM
> E/AndroidRuntime(14785): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> E/AndroidRuntime(14785): Process: com.muffly, PID: 14785
> E/AndroidRuntime(14785): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService: java.lang.RuntimeException: PluginRegistrantCallback is not set.
> E/AndroidRuntime(14785):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4043)
> E/AndroidRuntime(14785):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:229)
> E/AndroidRuntime(14785):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1917)
> E/AndroidRuntime(14785):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
> E/AndroidRuntime(14785):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226)
> E/AndroidRuntime(14785):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7592)
> E/AndroidRuntime(14785):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> E/AndroidRuntime(14785):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
> E/AndroidRuntime(14785):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
> E/AndroidRuntime(14785): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: PluginRegistrantCallback is not set.
> E/AndroidRuntime(14785):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.startBackgroundIsolate(FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.java:157)
> E/AndroidRuntime(14785):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.onCreate(FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.java:77)
> E/AndroidRuntime(14785):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4031)
> E/AndroidRuntime(14785):    ... 8 more
> D/OOMEventManagerFK(14785): checkEventAndDumpForJE: 0
> I/Process (14785): Sending signal. PID: 14785 SIG: 9

pubspec.yaml

> firebase_core: ^0.5.0
>
> firebase_auth: ^0.18.4+1
>
> firebase_messaging: ^7.0.0-dev.15
>
> firebase_dynamic_links: ^0.5.0+11
>
> firebase_core: ^0.5.0

AndroidManifest.xml

```
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
                android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
                android:value="high_importance_channel" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with YOUR_SCHEME://YOUR_HOST -->
                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="muffly.page.link" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a separated file beside `MainActivity.kt` and name it `Application.kt` and type the following code inside it.

```kotlin
//Don't forget to change it to your app package name!!!
package com.your.packagename

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant

class Application : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {

  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    setPluginRegistrant(this)

  }

  override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
    FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry?.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
  }
}
```

Then, on your `AndroidMainfest.xml` add `android:name=".Application"` to your `application` tag

```xml
 <application
  ...
  android:name=".Application"

  >
```

Finally, add `firebase-messaging` to your `app/build.gradle`.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0"
}
```